# How to reanimate in javascript on click?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, resultset, solver

I have created animation using keyframes in css, how can re use that animation onclick?
I have to change background of the header on click, like carousel, and header must be animated on every click. But it is not working. I set header.style.animation to null and rewrite header.style.animation = 'animate-bg 1s linear' in each click, still not working

Comment: We can't guess without code. Please post a snippet.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add your animation to a class, you can trigger the animation just by removing and adding the class again.
This solution uses `setTimout` to be sure that the browser renders the deletion.

```js
document.getElementById("header").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.target.classList.remove("anim");
  setTimeout(function(){
    e.target.classList.add("anim");
  });
})
```

```css
@keyframes animate-bg {
  0%   {background-color: red;}
  25%  {background-color: yellow;}
  50%  {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}

.anim {
 animation: animate-bg 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Hello Header</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code in your question first.

Add a class "**active**" onclick button then

```
button.active header{
  animation: animate-bg 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Use the flag option to flag the question for closing and leave a comment on the question on how to improve it.